# Converting String to Int in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have column `Terms` in my table and it contains data like this:

```
30D, 40D, etc.
```

`D` represents days.

My question: how can I sum date in `Terms` column? How can I convert string to int?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just the letter 'D' ?

Comment: SELECT SUM(CAST(REPLACE(Terms,'D','') AS INT))  
    FROM <your Table>

Comment: Bri, i want to strip ni D and use the number.

Comment: Cool.  answer below should work.  Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use REPLACE to ditch the D and CONVERT to convert the varchar to a number....

```
SELECT SUM(CONVERT(int, REPLACE(Terms,'D',''))) FROM TableName
```

**Edit:**  Commentor is right, CAST would work too.

And I dont get all the down votes.  The guy's just asking a SQL question.

Jeez... Tough crowd.

**Edit2:**

OK, based on comments, it seems like you would like to get a "due date" from the terms (say, TODAY + 30D or "today + 30 days").  To do that, we'd need a DATE column.  OR, we can just use today's date (GETDATE())

**Assume your table has a date column called ... dt**

The SQL to pull dt+'30D' would require us to add 30 "days" to dt.

**DATEADD** will add days, and the aforementioned **CONVERT+REPLACE** combo will convert '30D' to just plain '30' ...

So, you end up with the following SQL:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, CONVERT(int, REPLACE(Terms,'D','')), dt) FROM TableName
```

1. The 'day' tells DATEADD to add days (that seems really obvious ... now),
2. the CONVERT+REPLACE tells it how many days to add
3. AND - dt is our column name.

SO - how about just adding "30D" to TODAY?  Easy.  We just swap out dt with GETDATE() ...

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, CONVERT(int, REPLACE(Terms,'D','')), GETDATE()) FROM TableName
```

Comment: Hi bri tnx .. sum with one field? where is the date?

Comment: OK.  so... what date does "30D" translate to?  30 days from today?  That's a little unclear in the original question...

Comment: im trying the code your given.. i will inform you if it is work..
but Thank in advance :)

Comment: *The 'd' tells DATEADD to add days* - and it would be even clearer (and would need no explanation at all) if you just used `DATEADD(DAY, ..` instead of abbreviating that first parameter.

Comment: hi bri tnx to you it woks for me..
but i facing another problem.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT    AVG(SALARY) - AVG(CONVERT(int, REPLACE(SALARY,'0',''))) 
FROM      EMPLOYEES;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32574488)

Comment: Hello Mark, i'm a reviewer of last answer on StackOverflow and I regret that your answer doesn't contain any explanation ... and that your example is buggy !!! Indeed, if SALARY is a STRING value and contains 10450, in your solution, salary INTEGER will be ... 1045 !!! Can you give us some explanation and try to resolve question using same data without introducing others errors ? Thanks